# send data with $state params angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I m new in angular and i don t understand why my data is not send from a controller to an other with state param i've got "undefined" in my console. Can you help me to fix this ?

My controller :

```
     .controller('RegistreCtrl', function ($scope, $stateParams,factotransaction,$state) {
            console.log("coucou");
            var mytoken = sessionStorage.getItem('token');
            factotransaction.send(mytoken).then(function(conf)

             {
                    console.log(conf);
                    $scope.datab = conf.data;
            })

            $scope.operation = function(id){



                $state.go('app.operation', { id: id });
                $state.params.id = id;



            }

    })


        .controller('OperationCtrl', function ($scope, $stateParams,factotransaction,$state) {



            var mytoken = sessionStorage.getItem('token');
            factotransaction.send(mytoken).then(function(conf){
                console.log(conf);
                conf.data.forEach(function(item){
                console.log($state.params.id);
                    if($state.params.id == item.id) {

                        $scope.item = item;
                        console.log(item);
                    }
                });
            });
```

My app.js :

```
  .state('app.operation', {
        url: '/operation',
        views: {
          'menuContent': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/operation.html',
            controller: 'OperationCtrl'
              }
          }
      })
;
```

Comment: Try `$state.current.params.id`, and change the url of the state to `url: '/operation/:id',`

Comment: Wow it works ! the problem was the url ! put it as a answer pls then i will validate :)

Comment: Thanks, but I don't have enough time to write a complete well-written question. Glad I was able to help :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to include params In the route itself first.

```js
.state('albums.name',{
            //url:'',
            templateUrl:'views/tpls/player.tpl.html',
            controller:'playerCtrl as vm',
            params:{
                album:null,
            }
        });
```

Example on how i pass object called album to the route.